# Ansible: Start role if service present

Tags: service, ansible

I want to run a role, but before i want to check if the program is already installed.

I guessed I should use the module "service" ? In Ubuntu the service is pointed with **[ ? ] arkeia**

I tried:

```
  tasks:
    - name: check arkeia
      service: name=arkeia state=started
      register: result

  roles:
    - { role: arkeia, when: result==true }
```

Otherwise if it is not possible to check if a program is already installed, i would check if the program folder is present and next start the role.

EDIT:

Thanks for your fast answer!

I think my flaw is the "when:" command.
But how can I check if the result is false?

**I am getting following error:**

```
> PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [managed-centos]
ok: [managed-ubuntu]
ok: [ansible]

TASK: [arkeia | check arkeia] ************************************************* 
ok: [ansible]
ok: [managed-ubuntu]
ok: [managed-centos]

TASK: [arkeia | create directory] ********************************************* 
skipping: [managed-centos]
skipping: [managed-ubuntu]
changed: [ansible]

TASK: [arkeia | download sources debian] ************************************** 
skipping: [managed-centos]
skipping: [managed-ubuntu]
changed: [ansible]

TASK: [arkeia | download sources cent_os] ************************************* 
skipping: [ansible]
skipping: [managed-ubuntu]
fatal: [managed-centos] => error while evaluating conditional: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and p.stat.exist == false

TASK: [arkeia | install Arkeia debian] **************************************** 
fatal: [ansible] => error while evaluating conditional: ansible_os_family == "Debian" and p.stat.exist == false
fatal: [managed-ubuntu] => error while evaluating conditional: ansible_os_family == "Debian" and p.stat.exist == false

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/vagrant/arkeia.retry

ansible                    : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=1    failed=0   
managed-centos             : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
managed-ubuntu             : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

**This is my Playbook:**

```
- name: check arkeia
  stat: path=/etc/init.d/arkeia
  register: p

- name: create directory
  file: state=directory path={{ install_directory }}
  when: p.stat.exists == False

- name: download sources debian
  get_url: url={{ arkeia_deb_url }} dest={{ install_directory }}/{{ deb_filename }}
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian" and p.stat.exists == false

- name: download sources cent_os
  get_url: url={{ arkeia_centos_url }} dest={{ install_directory }}/{{ centos_filename }}
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and p.stat.exist == false

- name: install Arkeia debian
  sudo: yes
  apt: deb={{ install_directory }}/{{ deb_filename }}
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian" and p.stat.exist == false

- name: install Arkeia centos
  sudo: yes
  yum: name={{ install_directory }}/{{ centos_filename }}
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and p.stat.exist == false
```

**Debug result:**

```
TASK: [arkeia | debug msg="{{ p }}"] ****************************************** 
ok: [ansible] => {
    "msg": "{'invocation': {'module_name': u'stat', 'module_args': u'path=/etc/init.d/arkeia'}, 'stat': {'exists': False}, 'changed': False}"
}
ok: [managed-ubuntu] => {
    "msg": "{'invocation': {'module_name': u'stat', 'module_args': u'path=/etc/init.d/arkeia'}, 'stat': {'exists': False}, 'changed': False}"
}
ok: [managed-centos] => {
    "msg": "{'invocation': {'module_name': u'stat', 'module_args': u'path=/etc/init.d/arkeia'}, 'stat': {'uid': 0, 'exists': True, 'woth': False, 'mtime': 1421377097.0, 'inode': 67318822, 'isgid': False, 'size': 1224, 'wgrp': False, 'isuid': False, 'isreg': True, 'pw_name': 'root', 'gid': 0, 'ischr': False, 'wusr': True, 'xoth': True, 'rusr': True, 'nlink': 1, 'issock': False, 'rgrp': True, 'gr_name': 'root', 'path': '/etc/init.d/arkeia', 'xusr': True, 'atime': 1427813706.6750975, 'md5': '52de32627765e8f6e9ff8c5eee7ba232', 'isdir': False, 'ctime': 1427453340.1586156, 'isblk': False, 'xgrp': True, 'dev': 64769, 'roth': True, 'isfifo': False, 'mode': '0755', 'checksum': 'ddd459110d743402d9e18cfe4b3e032faaf54ba1', 'islnk': False}, 'changed': False}"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ... so simply :)

```
- name: create directory
  file: state=directory path={{ install_directory }}
  when: p.stat.exists == False

- name: download sources debian
  get_url: url={{ arkeia_deb_url }} dest={{ install_directory }}/{{ deb_filename }}
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian" and p.stat.**exists** == **f**alse

- name: download sources cent_os
  get_url: url={{ arkeia_centos_url }} dest={{ install_directory }}/{{ centos_filename }}
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and p.stat.**exist** == **f**alse
```

Write exists and false with a upper "F" and it works...

Answer (score 1):

`service` module doesn't allow you to get current status. If the service doesn't exist module execution would fail.

You can either run `shell: service arkeia status` or `shell: ps -eaf | grep -w arkeia` or [check for file's existance with `stat`](http://docs.ansible.com/stat_module.html)

Other thing you are doing wrong is using the registered variable incorrectly. It's value is a `dict` (or map) with keys like `rc, stdout, stdout_lines, stderr, ...`. So e.g. to use `stat` module you would do this:

```
- stat: path=/etc/init.d/arkeia
  register: p
- debug: msg="/etc/init.d/arkeia exists and is a file"
  when: p.stat.isreg is defined and p.stat.isreg
```

If you don't know the contents of result then `debug` and print it so you know what you're accessing:

```
- name: check arkeia
  service: name=arkeia state=started
  register: result
- debug: msg="result={{ result }}"
```